# Download link in GitHub markdown

Tags: github, hyperlink, download, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to add a link in my `README.md` to download a file (let's say `file.txt`). I tried doing a normal link (`[click here](https://.../file.txt)`) and I even tried `<a href="https://.../file.txt" download="file.txt">click here</a>` but neither tries worked.

How can I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which precise URL did you use, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd rather not show the exact URL I use as it contains sensible data, the point here being that it doesn't work whether it be a `txt` file, a `js` file, a `xml` file... As for the two tests I gave here, it just generated a normal hyperlink that redirected to the raw content of the file instead of downloading it. When I added the `download` prop in the markdown it generated a `<a>` without it.